# Extracting two lines if pattern exist in the second line + clean + remove duplicates (Whatsapp extraction)

Tags: awk, sed

I want to search through a WhatsApp conversation (dumped as txt file) for any message containing  the string "I will tell to your mom" as well as the message before it.

However, I need to be able to match variations of the search string such as:
 - tell to your mom !!
 - teLl to Your Mom !!!!!!

Those should also be considered the same if same wording appears in the line before.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what format you have the transcript in. I assume you're not expecting for help on how to do this in WhatsApp itself, so have you exported the conversation to a text file? Can we see an example of it? And, this time, without oversharing.

Comment: @don_crissti Similar, but not quite the same. Here, OP wants case-insensitive search for a string longer than one char.

Comment: @don_crissti: I don't mind deletion. I figured, there is probably a dupe/similar_q somewhere. For the record, I see the similarity too, but both OPs did not, and chose to use very different keywords in the title, so It may help future googleability to keep both.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` was built for this.

to search case_-i_nsensitive, and return 1 line _B_efore, use similar to

`grep -i -B1 tell\ to\ your\ mom your_msg_dump_with_each_msg_on_seperate_line.txt`

Comment: Ok I reached full answer with this :

grep -i -B1 'tell to your mom' dump.txt | awk -F "-" '/1/ {print $2}' | awk '!seen[$0]++'

First awk removes date and time, the second removes duplicate lines. The result is quite satisfying.